# HTTPD (apache) randomly crashes on Unix web server

Tags: apache, unix, centos, server, plesk

I've been battling this problem for awhile now. I have about 30 client sites on a VPS Plesk 11.0.9 running on CentOS.

Every few days, apache/HTTPD suddenly crashes and all the client sites become inaccessible (I can still access the Plesk panel and SSH fine).

The only way to get it working again is to log into SSH and run

```
# service httpd restart
```

Here is the error log, (the pertinent area), if anyone can see what the problem is the help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[Thu Aug 27 23:30:59 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Thu Aug 27 23:30:59 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Thu Aug 27 23:30:59 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Thu Aug 27 23:30:59 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Aug 28 04:45:59 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 22179 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 28 10:05:57 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 26169 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 28 14:15:21 2015] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11620
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11641
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11653
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11652
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11624
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11622
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11633
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11660
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11692
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:43 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11640
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11697
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11696
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11695
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11694
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11693
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11674
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11669
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11700
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11698
[Fri Aug 28 21:43:47 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 11632
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.5', found '2.6.6'.
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib64/python26.zip:/usr/lib64/python2.6/:/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2:/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk:/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old:/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload'.
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 50 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 28 21:58:29 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
```

It happened again here:

```
[Sun Aug 30 18:24:33 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 15544 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Sun Aug 30 19:27:05 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 16277 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Mon Aug 31 02:58:58 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 32331 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

Comment: In your log: [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. Let's hope it solves to problem, I'll post on here if it happens again